# How to append rows of a dataframe into different lists based on an earlier value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe structured like this:

TKL      Reg Hours    Ovt Hours

TKL:1

Employee1 40            0

Employee2 20            0

TKL:2

Employee3 40            1.5

Employee4 20            0

Employee5 20            0

TKL:3

Employee6 40            5

I'm trying to figure out a way to separate the data frame into a lists of data frames where each list is a new TKL so I can aggregate the total number of regular and overtime hours worked per TKL. I've tried to use `df.iloc[:df.loc[df.TKL.str.contains('TKL',na=False)].index[0]]` in a for loop but this only pulls the first TKL only.

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First we identify rows which contains `TKL:`, and then split data frame base of those rows (the first for loop in my code) and append each small data frame to `df_list`. after loop is finished `df_list` contains multiple small data frames.

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(['TKL: 1',
 'Employee1 #hoursworked #ovtHours',
 'Employee2 #hoursworked #ovtHours',
 'TKL: 2',
 'Employee3 #hoursworked #ovtHours',
 'Employee4 #hoursworked #ovtHours',
 'Employee5 #hoursworked #ovtHours',
 'TKL: 3',
 'Employee6 #hoursworked #ovtHours'])

 df
                                  0
# 0                            TKL: 1
# 1  Employee1 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 2  Employee2 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 3                            TKL: 2
# 4  Employee3 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 5  Employee4 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 6  Employee5 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 7                            TKL: 3
# 8  Employee6 #hoursworked #ovtHours

ind_ = df[df[0].str.contains("TKL:")].index.to_list() + [len(df)]

df_list = []
for e,i in enumerate(ind_[:-1]):
    df_ = df[i:ind_[e+1]]
    df_list.append(df_.reset_index(drop=True))


for DF in df_list:
    print(DF.to_string())
    print("-----------")

                                  0
# 0                            TKL: 1
# 1  Employee1 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 2  Employee2 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# -----------
#                                   0
# 0                            TKL: 2
# 1  Employee3 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 2  Employee4 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# 3  Employee5 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# -----------
#                                   0
# 0                            TKL: 3
# 1  Employee6 #hoursworked #ovtHours
# -----------
```

if you need to keep original index (in main data frame) for small data sets, then replace the code `df_list.append(df_.reset_index(drop=True))` to `df_list.append(df_)`